# Using someone for a specific purpose and then discarding them right afterwards

Tags: single-word-requests

Korean has a lot of four-word phrases, typically originating in Chinese.
One of them – 토사구팽, (Revised Romanization) transliteration *to sa gu
paeng* – is literally translated as “rabbit killed, dog thrown away”, or
a little more dynamically, “kill the dog after hunting season”.

Practically, it describes a person who *uses* people. Is there a word in
English for someone who makes a practice of this?

Comment: If a person is used; ''used like a tissue just to be chucked away/thrown away/got rid of'' comes to my mind first

Comment: "Seduced and abandoned" is the closest I can think of.

Comment: This one derived from the lyrics of 'part of me' song by Katy Perry: $$ _.. you chewed me up and spit me out.._ $$ if someone used you and then threw you away :P

Comment: A "politician".

Comment: "Exploiter" comes to mind, but that's not quite what you're looking for, I'm afraid. Give me some time, I'll think of something. This is interesting. It should be a pretty common word denoting a wide-spread phenomenon, but I'm stumped. Bummer.

Comment: I'd translate the phrase as "nothing but a [***means to an end***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Means_to_an_end)."  But if you're looking for a term for a person who thinks that way, it's perhaps *machiavellian*.

Comment: "Capitalist", in its worst, most unethical sense.

Answer (score 2):

There are many colorful and informal words for such a person(!), but one that I think would make it into formal speech would be a "user"—which has a negative sense of someone who exploits people for their own ends and then discards them, as it were. It's sometimes lengthened to "user and abuser".

In recent popular lore, there's a "wombat"—one who "eats, roots and leaves" … based on the Australian animal that supposedly "eats roots and leaves".

Online, there are also "vampires", as in "help vampires", who suck the blood out of others by endlessly asking for help but rarely, if ever, returning the favor or saying thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, ***leech***.

> : a person who stays around other people and uses them for personal gain [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leech)
>
> : someone who calls themselves a friend but they only use you until someone better comes along to feed off. *Jasper was such a leech, he would use people for there drugs, money and sex than move onto the next victim to suck dry.* [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=leech)